# Good practice -- Redirection in models? -- Rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have a `Search` model and controller. The business logic is that if the user's keyword exact matches a product's model number, redirect them to the product page.

In this situation, should I just do the redirection from inside the model (where most of the logic resides already)?

Or should I return a flag or something to the controller so I can handle the redirect?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

THe model object cannot ans shall never do a redirect. The application logic is the duty of the controller, so the controller should ask the model object (as result of a request) if the product matches a model number, and then the controller does the redirect. The model object should not know anything about controller or views. This is part of the ["Model-View-Controller concept"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) this is implemented by Rails.

Rails implements the model as the [ActiveRecord pattern](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/activeRecord.html), so it is ok that the model object is responsible for the database, and that includes the search on the database. See the many options you have in the [Rails Guides for ActiveRecord Queries](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html) to see what falls in the responsibility of the model objects.

Comment: Is it ok to have a run_search function in the model which does all the searching the db (across multiple models) or is it best to have the controller do that as well?

Answer (score 4):

Always remember MVC pattern: [MVC in Rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#the-mvc-architecture)

Model must not take care of redirection or some other stuff that related to controller. Let redirection be in controller.